# Finding text duplicates - easy to implement

Tags: algorithm, text, duplicates

I am looking for some nice easy to implement algorithms to find duplicate texts in my cms.
Actually I am saving text to extra column with removed white spaces and made all characters lowcase so I can find duplicates if they are different by amount of spaces and letter cases, but it's not enough.

How can i handle situation where two texts are different by few characters and i also want them to be recognized as duplicates?

Comment: Read up about "edit distance".

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this problem is to use a Soundex check. You convert each word to its Soundex equivalent, eliminate small words, and if the records are the same, its a match. Crude, but effective.